# What is the role of the round counter in the key schedule of PRESENT?

Tags: key-schedule, present

Currently I am working on PRESENT block cipher implementation (Hardware) and I am unable to understand the role of round counter in key scheduling part of cipher.

Can some share some insight on round counter and its working?

Comment: Can you say more about what research you've already done with references, and be more specific about where you're stuck?

Comment: I would assume it has the same purpose as Rcon in the AES key schedule

Answer (score 2):

to prevent self-similarity of key scheduling

The importance of constant addition (not only present cipher) appears in preventing key schedule-based attacks  such as slide attack ,related key attacks and other structural attacks such as: invariant subspace attack , and nonlinear invariant subspace attacks.

paragraph  5.4 Key schedule attacks in original [Present Block cipher](http://www.lightweightcrypto.org/present/present_ches2007.pdf)
answers your questions.